# Why does PayPal Iframe stays above the fixed navbar?

Tags: html, css, paypal

I've added the PayPal Checkout button from this link [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/#).  The problem I encountered is that iframe where PayPal buttons are present stay above my fixed navbar on the page. Why is this happening and how do I put it back at the top?

I've tried to read the documentation but nothing seems to mentions this behavior. I've also tried to change the z-index to my navbar, but that didn't help.

Here is css of my navbar.

```css
.top {
  background-color: black;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top"></nav>
```

Comment: give link to your site pls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your CSS, target the iframe element and try adding this code

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Comment: You can also target the parent div of the paypal button.

Comment: Adding `!important` to that z-index made it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```css
iframe {
  z-index: 0 !important;
}
```

This CSS code snippets can work for your case.
I faced the same problem on my WordPress installation, and I was able to fix the issue with this. I hope it will be useful to you.